# How to probably insert proof by induction in wolframalpha

Tags: induction, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to get this into wolframalpha.com by doing the "prove by induction" command to check my results.

However I'm not sure how to insert it.

[image: See attached picture]

[image: Result in Wolfram]

Comment: Click on Step-by-Step (you may need to purchase an account, but sometimes it will do a step at a time). I was able to get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing

`prove by induction sum of (-1)^i(2i +1) for i from 0 to n equals (-1)^n (n+1) for n > 0`

seems to be good enough.

And by the way, your proof seems about right!

Comment: Thanks. But I do not seem to get the result correctly in wolfram Alpha. What am I missing? See added picture in edits

Comment: Doing step by step works.Thanks